# SAS - Output text file doesn't contain the exact spaces

Tags: sas

I am trying to write a SAS output file from a work table.  I inserted blank values '    '  (contains 4 spaces) for the output column.  However, when I output to a text file, it shows only one space '' (Example below, Sequence_number)
Is there a way I can include a format and have all the four spaces as output:
Something like below(sequence number should have 4 blank spaces)

```
 create table work.mech_temp_final as
      (select put(mt.chq_srl_nbr, z12.) as chq_srl_nbr
            , "    " as sequence_number
       from work.settl mt);
```

output as

```
12345|    |
```

rather than

```
12345||
```

Comment: You talk about making a TEXT file and show code that would be used to create a DATASET.  So which one is the issue?  If you are trying to create a TEXT file then show the code you used to write the text file.  If you are taking about the content of a dataset then I am even more perplexed.  SAS stores all character variables as fixed length.  Short values are padded with spaces.

Comment: Why are you showing those `|` characters in the output?  Are you trying to write a delimited file?  Delimited files do not have any place to store leading or trailing spaces. If you want to write a fixed column file you don't need to include those `|` characters, they will just make the file larger without adding any value.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using PROC EXPORT, use a data step with a `put` statement to generate the pipe-delimited file. If you have many variables to output, you can generate the required code using dictionary tables, save it to a macro variable, and use it in the `put` statement.

```
data _null_;
    set sashelp.cars(rename=(horsepower = chq_srl_nbr) );
    file "C:\test.txt";

    sequence_number = '    ';

    /* Create a header */
    if(_N_ = 1) then put 'chq_srl_nbr|sequence_number';

    /* Write data in the desired format */
    put chq_srl_nbr z12. '|' sequence_number $char4.;
run;
```

Comment: So instead of making a delimited file make a fixed position file but one with extra pipe characters added, perhaps to make it easier for humans to look at?

Comment: I guess that's what the OP is trying to do. I've never run into this before, but that's more or less what it seems to be.

Answer (score 1):

You can write directly write a fixed layout file from `Proc SQL` by using `ODS LISTING`.  Not recommended for many use cases.

Example:

```
title;
options nocenter nodate nonumber ps=max formchar='  ';

ods listing file='c:\temp\listing.txt';

proc sql;
  select 
    name format=$CHAR12.
  , ' '
  , age format=z9.
  from sashelp.class;
quit;

ods listing close;
```